# AngularJS : angular-ui-router redirects to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise path When I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've an SPA with `rails api` on backend and `angular` as front-end framework.

I'm using `stateProviders`, 
    `$urlRouterProvider` for managing states in my SPA I'm facing a small problem with ui-router. Whenever I refresh by hitting `Comand+R` from `Mac/Linux` or `F5` from `Windows`. It goes to the state where it was refreshed and right after it redirects to the `\dashboard`.

I want to stop this redirect I've read some articles, related question, and some github issues too but nothing made me successful.

Some of references where I did consult.

[Angular-ui-router state with $stateParams always redirects to $urlRouteProvider.otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511545/angular-ui-router-state-with-stateparams-always-redirects-to-urlrouteprovider)

[AngularJS : angular-ui-router always redirects to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896150/angularjs-angular-ui-router-always-redirects-to-urlrouterprovider-otherwise-l)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

After digging into those.

Here is my ui-router code:

`app.coffee`

```
'use strict'

  $stateProvider
    .state('app',
      url: '/'
      templateUrl: 'shared/app.html'
      abstract: true
      resolve:
        company: ['CompanyResource', '$rootScope', (CompanyResource, $rootScope) ->
          CompanyResource.current().$promise.then (company)->
            $rootScope.app.company = company
        ]
        user: ['Auth', '$state', '$rootScope', (Auth, $state, $rootScope)->
          if !$rootScope.signedin
            Auth.currentUser()
              .catch ->
                $state.go('login.signin')
        ]
    )
    .state('login',
      template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      abstract: true
      resolve:
        company: ['CompanyResource', '$rootScope', (CompanyResource, $rootScope) ->
          CompanyResource.current().$promise.then (company)->
            $rootScope.app.company = company
        ]
    )
    .state('login.signin',
      url: '/signin'
      templateUrl: 'templates/signin.html'
      controller: 'SigninCtrl'
      controllerAs: 'signin_ctrl'
    )
    .state('app.dashboard',
      url: 'dashboard'
      templateUrl: 'templates/admin/dashboard.html'
      title: 'Dashboard'
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
      controllerAs: 'dashboard_ctrl'
      resolve: []
    )
    .state('app.settings',
      url: 'settings'
      templateUrl: 'templates/admin/settings/base.html'
      controller: 'SettingsBaseCtrl'
      controllerAs: 'settings_ctrl'
      resolve:
        settings: ['AdminSettingsResource', (AdminSettingsResource) ->
          AdminSettingsResource.query().$promise
        ]
    )

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/dashboard'

angular
  .module('MYAPP', [
    'templates'
    'ngResource'
    'ngAnimate'
    'ngCookies'
    'ngStorage'
    'ngSanitize'
    'ngTouch'
    'ui.router'
    'ui.bootstrap'
    'duScroll'
    'angularMoment'
    'Devise'
  ])
  .config(['$compileProvider', ($compileProvider)->
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true)
  ])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) ->
    FastClick.attach document.body

    $rootScope.$state = $state
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams
  ])
  .config([
    '$stateProvider'
    '$urlRouterProvider'
  ])
```

Comment: Might be related to the inconsistent use of /URLs but I can barely read CoffeeScript. Note that `otherwise` can be passed a function which might help you track down the issue.

Comment: Also, your having to write `.$promise` on all service calls, although an orthogonal issue, indicates incorrect use of `$q.derfer()` and of `Promises` in general. This will likely bite you and indicates you are probably writing more code than you have to. Service methods should return a `Promise`, not a `Deferred`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  Ok for the `deffer` suggestion But my issue is different thanks for your advice although.. I have converted to `javascript` and created a `gist` for you please look into. https://gist.github.com/mutafaf/3ede1adbcc53a60df93177d3da652d67

Comment: Here is a plunkr where I tried to set it up (from your GIST). There is too much crap missing. I cannot stub out a dozen controllers and services. I almost did, here it is (WIP) https://plnkr.co/edit/8cDj32VDPpZX54dRNZmq?p=info. Sorry, but you cannot expect someone to rewrite all of that logic and invent all of those templates and stub out all of those controllers (I did try but I didn't have time to finish). Good luck to you

Comment: Also, in addition to being a terrible API, ngResource is awful for questions like this. I had to recreate all of your services stubbing them out with `$q` dependencies, ripping out your 8+ `module('app', [...])` dependencies. That is not even close to a minimal repro.